# Delphi 10 Seattle - little change in unit then all dcu file are recompiled

Tags: delphi, project, delphi-10-seattle, dcu

I have large project written in XE3 (about 2200 units). I did update IDE Delphi XE3 to Delphi 10 Seattle. When I adds or deletes methods in any unit (without form, without dfm) and I want running (F9), all units of project are compiling, this continues very long time. In XE3 is absent this problem. I have dcu files in the same folder. I did even new project file (dpr and dproj) in Delphi 10 but it did not work.

Comment: Does your XE3 have installed IDEFixPack while 10 does not? Afair it has some fixes for issues in that area - so when you are moving from a version that has it installed to a new version that does not have it it looks like a regression while the bug also existed in the old version but was fixed via the plugin.

Comment: I have IDEFixPack in XE3 and in 10.